# Send data from a form to another component of the same level -angular

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am new to angular i have this component :

**curva-form.componente.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { CurvaModel } from '../../../models/curva/curva.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-curva-form',
  templateUrl: './curva-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./curva-form.component.css']
})
export class CurvaFormComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = "Curva de Crecimiento Y Desarrollo";
  curva: CurvaModel;


  //Formulario
  curvaDocumentForm: FormGroup;

  //Condicionales
  loading: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) {

     }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.curvaDocumentForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      peso: ["", Validators.required],
      talla: ["", Validators.required],
      perimetro: ["", Validators.required],
  });
  }
}
```

**su html**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-title>
      <div fxLayout="row wrap" ng-reflect-fx-layout="row wrap">
        <div class="p-10" fxFlex.gt-sm="0" fxFlex.gt-xs="0" fxFlex="0">
          {{ title }}
        </div>

        <div
          class="p-10"
          fxFlex.gt-sm="55"
          fxFlex.gt-xs="55"
          fxFlex="100"
        ></div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-title>


<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
  <!-- Curva crecimiento y desarrollo form -->
  <mat-step [stepControl]="curvaDocumentForm">
    <form [formGroup]="curvaDocumentForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Datos del Menor</ng-template>
      <div
            fxLayout="row wrap"
            ng-reflect-fx-layout="row wrap"
            style="flex-flow: row wrap; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;"
          >
          <div
              class="p-10"
              fxFlex.gt-sm="33"
              fxFlex.gt-xs="33"
              fxFlex="33"
              style="flex: 1 1 33%; box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 33%;"
            >
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Ingrese el Peso (kg)*</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          placeholder="Ingrese el Peso"
          formControlName="peso"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Ingrese la Talla (cm) *</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          placeholder="Ingrese la Talla"
          formControlName="talla"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Ingrese el Perimetro Cefalico (cm)*</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          placeholder="Ingrese el Perimetro Cefalico"
          formControlName="perimetro"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <button
      (click)="Calcular()"
          class="m-t-20"
          color="primary"
          mat-raised-button
          [disabled]="loading"
           mat-button matStepperNext>Calcular</button>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
<router-outlet><app-curva-grafico></app-curva-grafico></router-outlet>
```

I want to send the data of that form to the next component (these components are on the same level - module), I have read something about input and output, but I don't understand it very well.

**curva-grafico.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-curva-grafico",
  templateUrl: "./curva-grafico.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./curva-grafico.component.css"],
})
export class CurvaGraficoComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  public lineChartData: Array<any> = [
    // peso para la tall B 0 - 2
    /* { data: [3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9,4,4.2,
      4.3,4.4,4.5,4.7,4.8,5,5.1,5.3,5.4,5.6,5.8,
      6,6.1,6.3,6.5,6.7,6.9,7.1,7.2,7.4,7.6,7.8,
      8,8.1,8.3,8.5,8.6,8.8,8.9,9.1,9.3,9.4,9.6,
      9.7,9.9,10,10.2,10.3,10.5,10.6,10.8,10.9,
      11.1,11.2,11.3,11.5,11.6,11.8,11.9,12.1,
      12.2,12.3,12.5,12.6,12.7,12.8,13,13.1,13.2,
      13.3,13.4,13.6,13.7,13.8,13.9,14,14.2,14.3,
      14.4,14.6,14.7,14.9,15,15.2,15.3,15.5,15.6,
      15.8,15.9,16.1,16.2,16.4,16.5,16.7,16.8,17,
      17.1,17.3,17.4,17.6,17.7,17.9,18,18.2,18.4,
      18.5,18.7,18.9,19.1,19.2,19.4,19.6,19.8,20,
      20.2,20.4,20.6,20.8,21,21.2,21.5,21.7,21.9,
      22.1,22.4,22.6,22.8,23.1,23.3,23.6,23.8,24.1], label: 'SD3'},
    { data: [3,3.1,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9,
      4,4.1,4.2,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.8,4.9,5.1,5.3,5.4,5.6,
      5.8,5.9,6.1,6.3,6.4,6.6,6.8,7,7.1,7.3,7.4,7.6,
      7.7,7.9,8,8.2,8.3,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.9,9,9.2,9.3,
      9.4,9.6,9.7,9.8,10,10.1,10.2,10.4,10.5,10.6,
      10.8,10.9,11,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,
      11.9,12,12.1,12.2,12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.7,
      12.8,13,13.1,13.2,13.3,13.5,13.6,13.7,13.9,
      14,14.2,14.3,14.5,14.6,14.7,14.9,15,15.1,15.3,
      15.4,15.6,15.7,15.8,16,16.1,16.3,16.4,16.5,
      16.7,16.8,17,17.1,17.3,17.5,17.6,17.8,18,18.1,
      18.3,18.5,18.7,18.8,19,19.2,19.4,19.6,19.8,
      20,20.2,20.4,20.6,20.8,21,21.2,21.4,21.7,21.9], label: 'SD2'},
    { data: [2.7,2.8,2.9,3,3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,
      3.6,3.8,3.9,4,4.1,4.2,4.4,4.5,4.7,4.8,5,5.1,
      5.3,5.4,5.6,5.7,5.9,6.1,6.2,6.4,6.5,6.7,6.8,
      7,7.1,7.2,7.4,7.5,7.6,7.8,7.9,8,8.2,8.3,8.4,
      8.5,8.7,8.8,8.9,9,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.8,9.9,
      10,10.1,10.2,10.3,10.4,10.6,10.7,10.8,10.9,11,
      11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,
      12,12.1,12.2,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.8,12.9,13,13.2,
      13.3,13.4,13.5,13.7,13.8,13.9,14.1,14.2,14.3,
      14.4,14.6,14.7,14.8,14.9,15.1,15.2,15.3,15.5,
      15.6,15.7,15.9,16,16.2,16.3,16.5,16.6,16.8,16.9,
      17.1,17.3,17.4,17.6,17.8,17.9,18.1,18.3,18.5,
      18.6,18.8,19,19.2,19.4,19.6,19.8,20], label: 'SD1'},
     { data: [2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,2.9,3,3.1,3.2,3.3,
      3.4,3.5,3.6,3.8,3.9,4,4.1,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.7,4.8,
      5,5.1,5.3,5.4,5.6,5.7,5.9,6,6.1,6.3,6.4,6.5,6.7,
      6.8,6.9,7,7.1,7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,7.7,7.9,8,8.1,8.2,
      8.3,8.4,8.5,8.6,8.8,8.9,9,9.1,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,
      9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,10,10.1,10.2,10.3,10.4,10.4,10.5,
      10.6,10.7,10.8,10.9,11,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,
      11.7,11.9,12,12.1,12.2,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.7,12.8,
      13,13.1,13.2,13.3,13.4,13.5,13.7,13.8,13.9,14,
      14.1,14.3,14.4,14.5,14.6,14.8,14.9,15,15.2,15.3,
      15.4,15.6,15.7,15.9,16,16.2,16.3,16.5,16.6,16.8,
      16.9,17.1,17.3,17.4,17.6,17.8,17.9,18.1,18.3], label: 'SD0' }, 
    { data: [2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,
      3,3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9,4,4.2,
      4.3,4.4,4.6,4.7,4.9,5,5.1,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6,
      5.8,5.9,6,6.1,6.2,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9,
      7,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.5,7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9,8,8.1,8.2,
      8.3,8.4,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.8,8.8,8.9,9,9.1,9.2,
      9.3,9.4,9.5,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,10,10.1,10.2,
      10.3,10.4,10.5,10.6,10.7,10.8,11,11.1,11.2,
      11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.8,11.9,12,12.1,12.2,
      12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.7,12.8,12.9,13.1,13.2,
      13.3,13.4,13.5,13.6,13.7,13.9,14,14.1,14.2,
      14.4,14.5,14.6,14.8,14.9,15,15.2,15.3,15.4,
      15.6,15.7,15.9,16,16.2,16.3,16.5,16.6,16.8], label: 'SD1Neg' },  
   { data: [2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.6,2.7,
    2.8,2.9,3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,4,
    4.1,4.2,4.3,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.8,5,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,
    5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9,6,6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7,
    6.8,6.9,7,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,7.6,7.7,7.8,
    7.9,8,8.1,8.2,8.3,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.7,8.8,
    8.9,9,9.1,9.1,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,
    10,10.1,10.2,10.4,10.5,10.6,10.7,10.8,10.9,11,
    11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,
    12,12.1,12.2,12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.7,12.8,12.9,
    13,13.2,13.3,13.4,13.5,13.6,13.7,13.9,14,14.1,
    14.2,14.4,14.5,14.6,14.7,14.9,15,15.1,15.3,15.4], label: 'SD2Neg' }, 
    { data: [1.9,1.9,2,2.1,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.3,2.4,2.5,
      2.6,2.7,2.7,2.8,2.9,3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.6,3.7,
      3.8,3.9,4,4.1,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.8,4.9,5,
      5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9,6,6.1,6.2,
      6.3,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9,7,7.1,7.2,7.2,
      7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9,7.9,8,8.1,8.2,
      8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.8,8.9,9,9.1,9.2,
      9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,10,10.1,10.2,10.3,
      10.4,10.5,10.6,10.7,10.7,10.8,10.9,11,11.1,11.2,
      11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,12,12.1,12.2,
      12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.7,12.8,12.9,13,13.2,13.3,
      13.4,13.5,13.6,13.7,13.8,14,14.1,14.2], label: 'SD3Neg' },  */

    // Peso para la Talla B 2 - 5
    { data: [9.6,9.8,9.9,10.1,10.2,10.4,10.5,
      10.7,10.8,11.0,11.1,11.3,11.4,11.6,11.7,
      11.8,12.0,12.1,12.2,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.8,
      12.9,13.0,13.1,13.3,13.4,13.5,13.6,13.7,
      13.8,14.0,14.1,14.2,14.4,14.5,14.6,14.8,
      14.9,15.1,15.2,15.4,15.5,15.7,15.8,16.0,
      16.1,16.3,16.4,16.6,16.7,16.9,17.0,17.2,
      17.3,17.5,17.6,17.8,17.9,18.1,18.3,18.4,
      18.6,18.8,18.9,19.1,19.3,19.5,19.7,19.9,
      20.1,20.3,20.5,20.7,20.9,21.1,21.3,21.6,
      21.8,22.0,22.2,22.5,22.7,22.9,23.2,23.4,
      23.7,23.9,24.2,24.4,24.7,25.0,25.2,25.5,
      25.8,26.0,26.3,26.6,26.9,27.2,27.5,27.8,
      28.0,28.3,28.6,28.9,29.2,29.5,29.8,30.1
    ], label: '+3'},
    { data: [8.8,8.9,9.1,9.2,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.8,
      9.9,10.0,10.2,10.3,10.4,10.6,10.7,10.8,
      11.0,11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.6,11.7,11.8,
      11.9,12.0,12.1,12.2,12.3,12.4,12.6,12.7,
      12.8,12.9,13.0,13.1,13.3,13.4,13.5,13.7,
      13.8,13.9,14.1,14.2,14.4,14.5,14.7,14.8,
      14.9,15.1,15.2,15.3,15.5,15.6,15.8,15.9,
      16.0,16.2,16.3,16.5,16.6,16.7,16.9,17.0,
      17.2,17.4,17.5,17.7,17.9,18.0,18.2,18.4,
      18.5,18.7,18.9,19.1,19.3,19.5,19.7,19.9,
      20.1,20.3,20.5,20.7,20.9,21.1,21.3,21.5,
      21.8,22.0,22.2,22.4,22.7,22.9,23.1,23.4,
      23.6,23.9,24.1,24.4,24.6,24.9,25.1,25.4,
      25.6,25.9,26.1,26.4,26.6,26.9,27.2], label: '+2'},
    { data: [8.1,8.2,8.3,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.8,9.0,
      9.1,9.2,9.3,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,10.0,10.2,
      10.3,10.4,10.5,10.6,10.7,10.8,10.9,11.0,
      11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,
      11.9,12.1,12.2,12.3,12.4,12.5,12.7,12.8,
      12.9,13.1,13.2,13.3,13.5,13.6,13.7,13.9,
      14.0,14.1,14.2,14.4,14.5,14.6,14.7,14.9,
      15.0,15.1,15.3,15.4,15.5,15.7,15.8,15.9,
      16.1,16.2,16.4,16.5,16.7,16.9,17.0,17.2,
      17.3,17.5,17.7,17.8,18.0,18.2,18.4,18.5,
      18.7,18.9,19.1,19.3,19.5,19.7,19.8,20.0,
      20.2,20.4,20.7,20.9,21.1,21.3,21.5,21.7,
      21.9,22.1,22.4,22.6,22.8,23.0,23.3,23.5,
      23.7,23.9,24.1,24.4,24.6], label: '+1'},
     { data: [7.4,7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9,8.0,8.1,8.2,
      8.4,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.8,8.9,9.0,9.1,9.2,9.3,
      9.4,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,10.0,10.1,10.2,
      10.3,10.4,10.5, 10.6,10.7,10.8,10.9,11.0,
      11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.7,11.8,11.9,
      12.0,12.2,12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.8,12.9,
      13.0,13.1,13.2,13.4,13.5,13.6,13.7,13.8,
      13.9,14.1,14.2,14.3,14.4,14.6,14.7,14.8,
      14.9,15.1,15.2,15.4,15.5,15.6,15.8,15.9,
      16.1,16.2,16.4,16.5,16.7,16.8,17.0,17.2,
      17.3,17.5,17.7,17.8,18.0,18.2,18.3,18.5,
      18.7,18.9,19.1,19.2,19.4,19.6,19.8,20.0,
      20.2,20.4,20.6,20.8,21.0,21.2,21.4,21.6,
      21.8,22.0,22.2,22.4], label: '0' }, 
    { data: [6.9,7.0,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,
     7.7,7.8,7.9,8.0,8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.6,
      8.7,8.8,8.9,9.0,9.1,9.2,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,
      9.6,9.7,9.7,9.8,9.9,10.0,10.1,10.2,10.3,
      10.4,10.5,10.7,10.8,10.9,11.0,11.1,11.2,
      11.3,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,12.0,12.1,
      12.2,12.3,12.4,12.6,12.7,12.8,12.9,13.0,
      13.1,13.2,13.3,13.4,13.6,13.7,13.8,13.9,
      14.0,14.2,14.3,14.4,14.5,14.7,14.8,14.9,
      15.1,15.2,15.4,15.5,15.6,15.8,15.9,16.1,
      16.2,16.4,16.5,16.7,16.8,17.0,17.1,17.3,
      17.5,17.6,17.8,18.0,18.1,18.3,18.5,18.6,
      18.8,19.0,19.2,19.3,19.5,19.7,19.9,20.0,
      20.2,20.4], label: '-1' },  
   { data: [6.3,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9,7.0,
      7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9,7.9,
      8.0,8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.8,
      8.8,8.9,9.0,9.1,9.2,9.3,9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,
      9.7,9.9,10.0,10.1,10.2,10.3,10.4,10.5,
      10.6,10.7,10.8,10.9,11.0,11.1,11.2,11.3,
      11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,12.0,12.1,
      12.2,12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.8,12.9,13.0,
      13.1,13.2,13.3,13.4,13.6,13.7,13.8,13.9,
      14.0,14.2,14.3,14.4,14.5,14.7,14.8,14.9,
      15.1,15.2,15.3,15.5,15.6,15.8,15.9,16.0,
      16.2,16.3,16.5,16.6,16.8,16.9,17.1,17.2,
      17.4,17.5,17.7,17.9,18.0,18.2,18.3,18.5,
      18.6], label: '-2' }, 
    { data: [5.9,6.0,6.1,6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,
      6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9,6.9,7.0,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,
      7.4,7.5,7.6,7.7,7.7,7.8,7.9,8.0,8.0,8.1,
      8.2,8.3,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.7,8.8,8.9,
      9.0,9.1,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,
      10.0,10.1,10.2,10.3,10.4,10.5,10.6,10.7,
      10.8,10.9,11.0,11.1,11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,
      11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,12.0,12.1,12.2,
      12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.8,12.9,13.0,13.1,
      13.2,13.3,13.4,13.5,13.7,13.8,13.9,14.0,
      14.1,14.3,14.4,14.5,14.6,14.8,14.9,15.0,
      15.2,15.3,15.4,15.6,15.7,15.8,16.0,16.1,
      16.2,16.4,16.5,16.7,16.8,16.9,17.1], label: '-3' }, 
  ];

  public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = [
   65,65.5,66,66.5,67,67.5,68,68.5,69,69.5,70,70.5,
   71,71.5,72,72.5,73,73.5,74,74.5,75,75.5,76,76.5,77,77.5,
   78,78.5,79,79.5,80,80.5,81,81.5,82,82.5,83,83.5,84,84.5,
   85,85.5,86,86.5,87,87.5,88,88.5,89,89.5,90,90.5,91,91.5,
   92,92.5,93,93.5,94,94.5,95,95.5,96,96.5,97,97.5,98,98.5,
   99,99.5,100,100.5,101,101.5,102,102.5,103,103.5,104,104.5,
   105,105.5,106,106.5,107,107.5,108,108.5,109,109.5,110,110.5,
   111,111.5,112,112.5,113,113.5,114,114.5,115,115.5,116,
   116.5,117,117.5,118,118.5,119,119.5,120
  ];


  public lineChartOptions:  any = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Talla (cm)'
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 12
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{ 
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Peso (kg)'
        }
      }]
    },
    /* elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      }
    }, */
  };


  public lineChartColors: Array<any> = [
    {
      // SD3
      //backgroundColor: 'rgba (75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
      borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0)",
      fill: "rgba(25,118,210,0.1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(128,128,128)",
      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#000000",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(25,118,210,0.5)",
    },
    {
      // SD2
      //backgroundColor: 'rgba(38,218,210,0.1)',
      borderColor: "rgba(255,165,0)",
      fill: "rgba(25,118,210,0.1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(128,128,128)",
      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(38,218,210,0.5)",
    },
    {
      // SD1
      //backgroundColor: 'rgba(38,218,210,0.1)',
      borderColor: "rgba(255,255,0)",
      fill: "rgba(25,118,210,0.1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(128,128,128)",
      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(38,218,210,0.5)",
    },
    {
      // SD0
      //backgroundColor: 'rgba(38,218,210,0.1)',
      borderColor: "rgba(0,128,0)",
      fill: "rgba(25,118,210,0.1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(128,128,128)",
      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(38,218,210,0.5)",
    },
    {
      // SD1neg
      //backgroundColor: 'rgba(38,218,210,0.1)',
      borderColor: "rgba(255,255,0)",
      fill: "rgba(25,118,210,0.1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(128,128,128)",
      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(38,218,210,0.5)",
    },
    {
      // SD2neg
      //backgroundColor: 'rgba(38,218,210,0.1)',
      borderColor: "rgba(255,165,0)",
      fill: "rgba(25,118,210,0.1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(128,128,128)",
      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(38,218,210,0.5)",
    },
    {
      // SD3neg
      //backgroundColor: 'rgba(38,218,210,0.1)',
      borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0)",
      fill: "rgba(25,118,210,0.1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(128,128,128)",
      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(38,218,210,0.5)",
    },
  ];
  public lineChartLegend = true;
  public lineChartType = "line";

  ngAfterViewInit() {}

}
```

**su html**

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
<div fxFlex.gt-xs="50" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-title>Graficos</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Curva de Crecimiento Y Desarrollo</mat-card-subtitle>
        <canvas baseChart height="150" [datasets]="lineChartData" [labels]="lineChartLabels" [options]="lineChartOptions" [colors]="lineChartColors"
          [legend]="lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChartType">
        </canvas>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate the help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to be as brief as possible:

There are many ways you can communicate between components. The ones that you mentioned (using the `@Input()` and `@Output` decorators) are basically as follows:

#### `@Input()` - receives data from parent

This is as simple as it gets. You pass data to the child component like so:

```html
<!-- one-way binding - value moves from the parent to child -->
<app-custom-component [childVar]="parentVar" ></app-custom-component>
```

And declare it in the **child component's** `.ts` like so:

```js
// you will have to import Input from @angular/core
@Input() childVar: string;
```

#### `@Output()` - sends data to parent

It behaves just like an event. In fact, it **is** an event:

```js
// import Output and EventEmitter from @angular/core as well
@Output childChange: new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Then the parent has to listen to it:

```html
<!-- the $event carries the content you want to grab -->
<app-custom-component2 (childChange)="parentDoesSomething($event)"></app-custom-component2>
```

[**Docs here**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties).

With this, you can receive data from one component in the parent and send it to another. There **are** other ways you can communicate between components, like with [services](https://medium.com/@enriqueoriol/angular-service-component-communication-4933782af52c).

Actually, take a look at [**this article**](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). It covers a lot of stuff.

#### Example using `@Input()` and `@Output()`

I made a quick little example in [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpt4t6). Check it out in case you're having trouble implementing it.